# Database Seeders not working in Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, model

My objective is to populate my database based on CSV files that change every 24 hours. It is my understanding that Seeders will be perfect for this and can even be called programatically as needed. I put together the basic code and used the documentation from their website, however it is failing and even with debug enabled, the error message makes very little sense.

I have already tested and confirmed the DB connection is working, also commenting out all Seeder code except the "Truncate" line and sadly that doesn't even  seem to be processing. If I truncate from within the route it works, from the seeder's `run()` it does not.

How can I fix or at least troubleshoot this?

Route:

```
Route::get('seed', function()
{
    Artisan::call('db:seed');
});
```

Seeder:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        // Empty the 'PLAYERS' Table
        DB::table('players')->truncate();

        // Fetch the data from our CSV File
        $data = $this->seedFromCSV('export.csv', ',');

        foreach ($data as $player)
        {
            DB::table('players')->insert(
                [
                    'name' => $player['First Name'] . " " . $player['Last Name'],
                    'team' => '0',
                    'position' => '0',
                    'played' => $player['Played'],
                    'injury_status' => $player['Injury Indicator'],
                    'injury_type' => $player['Injury Details'],
                    'fd_salary' => $player['Salary'],
                    'fd_fppg' => $player['FPPG'],
                    'opponent' => '0'
                ]
            );
        }
    }

    private function seedFromCSV($filename, $deliminator = ",")
    {
        if(!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        $header = NULL;
        $data = array();

        if(($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
        {
            while(($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $deliminator)) !== FALSE)
            {
                if(!$header) {
                    $header = $row;
                } else {
                    $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
                }
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }

        return $data;
    }

}
```

Error:

```
FatalErrorException in compiled.php line 2057:
Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded
```

Comment: Why do you have to call special route to seed the database? Why not to use cli command `php artisan db:seed`?

Comment: I am on shared hosting and Laravel was installed via Softaculous. I can't run direct commands as I do not have the access to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by Laravel's Seeders being unable to run in a production environment, thus causing it to timeout. To resolve this, the force parameter can be passed as true and it will complete as expected.

```
Artisan::call('db:seed', array('--class' => 'DatabaseSeeder', '--force' => true));
```

Comment: Wherever you are right now, god bless you and thank you very much for your best answer, you've saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the import for the DB facade in your DatabaseSeeder class.

add this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I just tested it however and it still times out with the same error message. Is it possible to get any more informative details about whats actually making it fail?

Comment: truncate should be working now... maybe the script needs more than 30 seconds to run sometimes, so try to change the `max_execution_time` in your `php.ini`

Comment: Hmm, that log sadly just appears to be the same as what is shown in the browser. I doubt it needs longer than that, there is literally 1 DB entry and the DB is on localhost. Running the truncate() line from anywhere else such as the Route, Controller, etc. completes instantly.

Comment: Run composer dump-autoload

Comment: So after throwing in the towel, I tested the CLI command instead with shell_exec('cd ../laravel && php artisan db:seed'); which seems like it will work but reports Application In Production! Command Cancelled! Would the fact I need to cd to the laravel directory below public_html or that message have anything to do with why its not working programatically?

Comment: @BrettPowell Add `--force` option after `db:seed`. It will force Laravel to seed even if you are on production env.